# Strange loading on modal window - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, modal-dialog

When you click on any of this icon of the modules:
[image]

It opens a modal which loads a nivoslider (which is an external html).

This is the script of the moadl to load the external html:

```
/* Load Modal-Nivo slider */
$(function ($) {
    // Load dialog on page load
    //$('#basic-modal-content').modal();

    // Load dialog on click
    $('.basic').click(function (e) {
        var src = "nivo/demo.html";
            $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="330" width="830" style="border:0">', {
                    closeHTML:"",
                    containerCss:{ 
                            height:330, 
                            padding:0, 
                            width:830
                    },
     overlayClose:true
     });
     return false;
 });
 });
```

The problem I have is that if you move the mouse cursor out of the nivoslider, it shows like it is loading something, I have tried lot of things to fix it but I don´t know what it shows that. Aside from that, it loads the nivo very well, it´s just that "cursor loading" problem,
Any ideas to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your overlay has this style (see style.css )

```
#simplemodal-overlay {
  background-color: #000;
  cursor: wait;
}
```

change cursor to default